# RecyclerView holder UI not updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView extends from the list adapter. I want to adjust the visibility of components according to some conditions.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<VB>, position: Int) {
        setUi(getItem(position).isAdded)
    }


private fun setUi(
        isAdded: Boolean
    ) {
        if (isAdded) {
            binding.addBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            binding.addBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

Although is added works and goes inside the method, the ui is not updating the conditional.

Can you help me?

Comment: Check the value of isAdded, is its correct or not

Comment: I checked the status. But everything is working properly. the only problem is ui not updating.

Comment: can you share the xml and the adapter class

Comment: I am sending the data to my adapter by wrapping the Event class in the link (https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8) . This problem happens when I use the Event class. I have to use this class to observe the live data once. So I can't remove the Event class.